# Edit Mode Snap Problem

Tags: modeling

My English is nad. I am sorry. Blender dont snap in edit mode selected mesh. But snap other objects. Please help me.

https://streamable.com/q98hp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable "snap to self"

[image]